# Maximizing the a determinant of a matrix whose entries are one plus a scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, simplex

I have the following problem:

What are the vectors $\vec{r}_i$ that yield the maximal value of this determinant?
    \begin{equation}
 \det \left( \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
 \cdots & \vec{r}_1^T & \cdots \\
 \cdots & \vec{r}_2^T & \cdots \\
 \cdots & \vec{r}_3^T & \cdots \\
 \cdots & \vec{r}_4^T & \cdots
 \end{bmatrix}_{4 \times 3} \begin{bmatrix}
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 \vec{r}_1 & \vec{r}_2 & \vec{r}_3 & \vec{r}_4 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
 \end{bmatrix}_{3 \times 4}
 \right)
 \end{equation}
    where $\vec{r}_i$ are all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, s.t. $\left\vert \vec{r}_i \right\vert \leq 1 $. Simply put, the problem is maximizing the determinant of a matrix $A$ with $A_{ij} = 1+\vec{r}_i \cdot \vec{r}_j$, where $\vec{r}_i$ are all inside the unit sphere in three dimensions.

I think the solution is as follows: $\vec{r}_i$ all have unit norm, and if their end points form a tetrahedron. I.e.:
    \begin{equation}
 \vec{r}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 \sqrt{ 8/9 } \\
 0 \\
 -1 / 3
 \end{bmatrix} , \vec{r}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
 -\sqrt{ 2/9 } \\
 \sqrt{ 2/3 } \\
 -1 / 3
 \end{bmatrix} , \vec{r}_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
 -\sqrt{ 2/9 } \\
 -\sqrt{ 2/3 } \\
 -1 / 3
 \end{bmatrix} , \vec{r}_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation}
but I have no idea how to prove it. The only thing even remotely related I found when looking up, was the Cayley-Menger determinant:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant

and yet I couldn't find a clear connection between that and my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your determinant is $\det(X^TX)$, where
$$
X=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\
\vec{r}_1&\vec{r}_2&\vec{r}_3&\vec{r}_4}.
$$
Let
$$
U=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\vec{r}_1&\vec{r}_2&\vec{r}_3&\vec{r}_4}.
$$
Then $\det(X)=\sqrt{3}\det(U)$ and hence your determinant is equal to
$3\det(U)^2$.

Since $\|\vec{r}_j\|\le1$, each column of $U$ has norm $\le\sqrt{\frac13+1}=\sqrt{\frac43}$. Therefore, by QR factorisation, $|\det(U)|\le\left(\sqrt{\frac43}\right)^4=\frac{16}{9}$ and equality holds if and only if $U$ is a scalar multiple of an orthogonal matrix. It follows that the maximum possible value of $3\det(U)^2$ is $3\left(\frac{16}{9}\right)^2=\frac{256}{27}$. This occurs, e.g. when
$$
U=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\vec{r}_1&\vec{r}_2&\vec{r}_3&\vec{r}_4}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&-1&-1\\ 1&-1&1&-1\\ 1&-1&-1&1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. One question though: how did you know to divide the first row by $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @AmitTeeni If you don't divide it by $\sqrt{3}$, the norm of the first row will be different from the norm of each column. Hence the matrix cannot be orthogonal, the inequality is strict, and the upper bound isn't the best possible.